# How to constantly generate random numbers inside for i in range loop

Tags: python, loops, class, random, ursina

```
import random
world_size=8
for i in range(world_size)
   chunk_type=random.randint(1,2)
   print(chunk_type)
```

---

```
 import random
 class chunk_type():
      chunk_type=random.randint(1,2)
 world_size=8
 for i in range(world_size):
    chunk_type()
    print(chunktype.chunktype)
```

both pieces of code don't work

I am trying to make a 2d game using Ursina. All has gone well until I made terrain. The looping of terrain works well but when I try to make the types of chunks random the radiant function only works once. How do I fix this? By The Way I am new to stack overflow so this would be a great help.

The above code should output should output a string of 8 random numbers between 1 and 2.
I have tried update methods while true methods and the method for I in range. The radiant method only worked once so when I printed the variable for debugging it just reads all 1s or 2s. What can I do? There is no error messgae as the randiant function only works once.

Comment: Of course they don't work. Indentation matters in Python, plus you're missing some required syntactic elements. Post actual error messages. The vague statement "both pieces of code don't work" is not sufficient. Finally, this post shouldn't be here in the first place.  Go back and edit your original post to respond to the criticisms you received there.

Comment: In the second code example, the `chunk_type` is a static attribute of the class `chunk_type`, so it will only be set once when Python loads that file. Even when you instantiate a new instance of that class, the value will not change. You can change the value of the static variable if you wanted though: `chunk_type.chunk_type = random.randint(1,2)`. This questions goes into more depth about static variables/attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/class-static-variables-and-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only looking for integers you can do this.

```
import random

def chunk_type():
      return random.randint(1,2)

world_size=8

for i in range(world_size):
    random_int = chunk_type()
    print(random_int)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"... The above code should output should output a string of 8 random numbers between 1 and 2. I have tried update methods while true methods and the method for I in range. ..."*

Use a *"[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)"*.

```py
import random as r
n = 8
a = [r.randint(1, 2) for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: what is a ' list compreheshion'?

Comment: @OpGaming, it's a term used to describe the way _Python_ allows the iteration of a _collection_ in a single-line.  It's similar to a _functional interface_, _a = f(x)_.

Comment: Is it like a python dictionary inside a variable?

Comment: @OpGaming, no, it's not a _collection_.  It is a procedure, like a _[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))_ or a _"lambda"_.  It performs a _for-loop_, with optional conditions; all on one line, thus they coined it a _"comprehension"_.  If there is any fundamental _Python_ syntax I recommend learning, it would be this.  The documentation I linked in the answer explains it in detail.